# How to stop vim beeping every time I enter > in PHP

Tags: php, vim

Here's a PHP snippet

```
 $foo = array( 'bar' => 'baz' );
```

When I enter this in Vim, I will get a bell/beep on pressing `>`. This does not happen if I type `<something>`, so I think it's trying to be helpful in saying "ah, you've closed an angle bracket but you didn't open one!". But it's not helpful, it just seems not to understand the context: assignment to an associative array.

It also beeps/bells when I type `$foo->bar`.

I have `set ft=php`, which all seems to be working fine, other than this infuriating beep.

I know I can disable the beep altogether, but I'd rather keep the beep for things I really do need to be beeped at for. I know about visual bell, but I don't want a headache inducing flash every time I access a method, property or assign to a new array!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have the `set showmatch` line which, as you said, tries to be helpful and match open and closed brackets.

You can try to add the following line in your .vimrc:

```
au BufWinEnter *.php set mps-=<:>
```

or just

```
setlocal matchpairs-=<:>
```

in the PHP vim configuration.

Answer (score 4):

The beep is caused by the `'showmatch'` option trying to locate the corresponding `<`, which it can't. So, you can prevent the beep by either:

- removing angle brackets from the `'matchpairs'` option; however, this will also disable the functionality on HTML tag start / ends: `:setlocal matchpairs-=<:>`
- turn off `'showmatch'`; in contrast to the former, this unfortunately is a global setting: `set noshowmatch`

Comment: I have created a feature request to add a new option to avoid the beep in this case: https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/detail?id=319

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the bell during insert mode altogether:

```
" Disable bell during insert mode, to avoid beep with 'showmatch'.
" Source: https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/detail?id=319
augroup NoBellDuringInsert
    au!
    au InsertEnter * :call SetBell(1)
    au InsertLeave * :call SetBell(0)
augroup END

fun! SetBell(disable)
  if a:disable
    let s:mybell = [&eb, &vb, &t_vb]
    " need to set visualbell, else bell will still be called.
    set noeb vb t_vb=
  else
    let [&eb, &vb, &t_vb] = s:mybell
  endif
endfun
```

There is a patch pending for a new setting on the vim_dev mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/-jN4_nsSls0/Nbjbrh4jXYEJ

Comment: This is definitely a better answer for general purpose use. For example, disabling the error bell on Alt- linked commands do ```nnoremap <silent> <M-h> :call SetBell( 1 )<esc><C-W><Left>:call SetBell( 0 )<CR>```